# How to "Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers"?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, classpath

So, I'm trying to integrate Elasticsearch, but my Spring Boot Application can't start properly

My pom.xml file

```
<properties>
    <elasticsearch.version>6.8.0</elasticsearch.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    ....
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    ....
</dependencies>
```

And configuration Bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.contacts.demo.elasticsearch")
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Client client() throws UnknownHostException {
        Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();
        TransportClient transportClient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
        transportClient.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
        return transportClient;
    }
}
```

With this I'm getting

The following method did not exist:

```
org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.getLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Logger;
```

The method's class, org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.8.0/elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar!/org/elasticsearch/common/logging/Loggers.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.8.0/elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers

I've seen some same topics, but making elasticsearch.version property does not help me

Comment: try to add log4j jar file to your classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've overridden the version of `org.elasticsearch.client:transport` to be `6.5.4` while you appear to be using `6.8.0` of all of Elasticsearch's other modules. `org.elasticsearch.client:transport` is included in Spring Boot's dependency management for Elasticsearch so I'd recommend removing the `<version>` from your pom and using the managed version instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped, but I had overridden version because I was getting exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.mapping.put.PutMappingResponse
And now have this problem again

Comment: That sounds like progress at least. Have you posted another question for the `ClassNotFoundException`? If you do so, it would be useful to share the full stack trace as that will show what code is expecting to find the `PutMappingResponse`.

Comment: Not yet, but I've just downgraded my Elasticsearch server to 6.4.3 and it worked just fine with default Spring Boot Elasticsearch adapter